# SQL trigger Atualiza Stock

Tags: sql, sql-server

**LISTA_DE_PRODUTOS**

```
create table LISTA_DE_PRODUTOS (
   IDPRODUTO            numeric              identity,
   PRECO                money                null,
   DESIGNACAO           varchar(50)          null,
   ALCOOLICO            bit                  null,
   constraint PK_LISTA_DE_PRODUTOS primary key nonclustered (IDPRODUTO)
```

**ITENS**

```
create table ITENS (
   IDTRANSACAO          numeric              not null,
   IDITEN               numeric              identity,
   IDPRODUTO            numeric              not null,
   QUANTIDADE           decimal(10,2)        null,
   constraint PK_ITENS primary key nonclustered (IDTRANSACAO, IDITEN)
```

**TRANSACOES**

```
create table TRANSACOES (
   IDTRANSACAO          numeric              identity,
   IDPULSEIRA           numeric              not null,
   IDPOS                numeric              not null,
   IDLOJA               numeric              not null,
   VALOR_TOTAL          money                null,
   DATA_DA_TRANSACCAO   datetime             null,
   constraint PK_TRANSACOES primary key nonclustered (IDTRANSACAO)
```

**LOJAS_PRODUTOS**

```
create table LOJAS_PRODUTOS (
   IDLOJA               numeric              not null,
   IDPRODUTO            numeric              not null,
   STOCK_DISPONIVEL     float                null,
   constraint PK_LOJAS_PRODUTOS primary key (IDLOJA, IDPRODUTO)
```

Como é que crio um *trigger* de atualizar estoque com estas tabelas?

Com os seguintes detalhes:

Cada um dos itens da transação só pode ser adquirido se existir estoque suficiente na loja em que está a ser feita a transação. Caso não exista estoque suficiente de pelo menos um dos produtos, a transação e os respectivos itens não devem ser carregados.

Comment: E como deve ser a atualização do estoque? Acrescente na descrição do tópico os detalhes do que tem que ser feito e, principalmente, como.

Comment: "stock"!? Não seria "estoque"!?

Comment: Muito obrigado José. Já acrescentei os detalhes.